# Как остановить бесконечный цикл командой стоп, которую пишет пользователь в чате телеграм бота? Python

Tags: python, парсер, aiogram, asyncio, event-loop

Есть многопользовательский телеграм бот, который по команде запускает парсинг объявлений с сайта. Вызывается функция `start_parsing`, запускается цикл `While True`. При получении в чате команды `стоп`, хендлер ловит команду и вызывается функция `stop_parsing`, которая должна остановить работу бесконечного цикла

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="start"))
async def start_parsing(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="парсинг запущен")
    while True:
        #тут код с парсингом


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="stop"))
async def stop_parsing(message: types.Message):
    #тут код, который останавливает цикл While True из функции "start_parsing"
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="парсинг остановлен")
```

Частично проблема решилась созданием глобальной переменной `parsing_continue`. Цикл `While` при каждой итерации проверяет, что она равна `True`. А по команде стоп в функции `stop_parsing` эта переменная становится `False`.
Но это работает только для 1 пользователя. Когда их несколько, команда стоп тормозит парсер всех других пользователей, т.к. переменная глобальная

```
global parsing_continue


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="start"))
async def start_parsing(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="парсинг запущен")
    global parsing_continue
    parsing_continue = True
    while parsing_continue:
        #тут код с парсингом


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="stop"))
async def stop_parsing(message: types.Message):
    global parsing_continue
    parsing_continue = False
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="парсинг остановлен")
```

Возможно, в варианте с глобальной переменной поможет словарь, в котором ключом будут динамически создаваемые переменные `parsing_continue`, привязанные к id пользователя.
Или существует более подходящая конструкция, чем блокирующий цикл While True.
Может можно как-то создать задачу, которая будет активироваться при старте, и сниматься при стопе.

Сам в питоне новичок, с языком знаком по библиотеке aiogram для ботов. Нагуглил варианты с событийными циклами, creating task, event-loop и тд... Пока не разобрался, это то что нужно, или нет. Подозреваю, что это целая тема для изучения.
Буду благодарен если подскажите куда вообще копать

Comment: В чем проблема юзать хранилище fsm? Для каждого юзера оно отдельное

Comment: Можно подробнее какое решение вы предлагаете? 
С хранилищем не будет глобальной переменной. Как тогда динамически изменять ее значение в функции "start"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Записывайте `parsing_continue` в хранилище стейта.

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="start"))
async def start_parsing(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="парсинг запущен")
    # записываете в хранилище
    await state.update_data({"parsing_continue": True})
    # обязательно чтобы делалось именно так, не нужно это в переменную записывать
    while (await state.get_data()).get("parsing_continue"):
        print(1)
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="stop"))
async def stop_parsing(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    # просто обновляем данные
    await state.update_data({"parsing_continue": False})
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="парсинг остановлен")
```

Comment: Спасибо
Работает как надо